# DBIC-AJAX: Why is my array "undef"?

Tags: ajax, perl, catalyst

I'm using ajax to retrieve some values in a form. The backend uses a catalyst app. A specific field is giving me a hard time retrieving the values and I have no idea why...

Consider 4 fields containing several values each, sent via ajax.

```html
<input name="precedents_mandatory_no" type="checkbox" value="[% precedent.precedent_id -%]">
<input name="precedents_mandatory_yes" type="checkbox" value="[% precedent.precedent_id -%]">
<input name="mandatory_med_no" type="checkbox" value="[% precedent.precedent_id -%]">
<input name="mandatory_med_yes" type="checkbox" value="[% precedent.precedent_id -%]">
```

They are all sent and received properly, according to my debugs:

```
[debug] "POST" request for "subjects/add" from "127.0.0.1"
[debug] Body Parameters are:
.-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------.
| Parameter                           | Value                                |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| mandatory_med_no                    | 6, 7, 23                             |
| mandatory_med_yes                   | 8, 19                                                              |
| precedents_mandatory_no             | 6, 7                                 |
| precedents_mandatory_yes            | 8, 19, 23                            |

'-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------'
```

Now, to capture these values, I use Catalyst::Parameters like this.

```
my $req = $c->request;
my $params = $req->parameters;

my @mandatory_precedent           = ref $params->{precedents_mandatory_yes} ? @{$params->{precedents_mandatory_yes}} : $params->{precedents_mandatory_yes};
my @mandatory_precedent_treatment = ref $params->{mandatory_med_yes} ? @{$params->{mandatory_med_yes}} : $params->{mandatory_med_yes};
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should allow to create an array containing all the elements in both "mandatory_med_yes" and "precedents_mandatory_yes" parameters.

However, only **@mandatory_precedent** seems to be filled with the values, while **@mandatory_precedent_treatment** is undef. The following debug:

```
    print STDERR "DEBUG predecedents: \n".Dumper(@mandatory_precedent);
    print STDERR "DEBUG treatments: \n".Dumper(@mandatory_precedent_treatment);
```

Produces an output like:

```
DEBUG params: 
$VAR1 = {
          'mandatory_med_no' => [
                                '6',
                                '7',
                                '23'
                              ],
          'mandatory_med_yes ' => [
                                  '8',
                                  '19'
                                ],
          'precedents_mandatory_yes' => [
                                        '8',
                                        '19',
                                        '23'
                                      ],
          'precedents_mandatory_no' => [
                                       '6',
                                       '7'
                                     ],
        };
DEBUG predecedents: 
$VAR1 = '8';
$VAR2 = '19';
$VAR3 = '23';
DEBUG treatments: 
$VAR1 = undef;
```

So... any ideas why?

Comment: Someone voted to close with _more code needed_. I'm not sure which code they meant, but maybe you can include how you call this, or a full dump of `$params`. I think for a start this has a lot of good information already, but it's not obvious to me what's wrong.

Comment: Well, having to add more code actually pointed out the problem! There was an additional /s in the html name for mandatory_med_yes. Shame on me.

Comment: And there we have the rubber duck. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra space when defining the name for the problematic parameter... heh...

*cry*